# Cakephp AJAX calls not authenticating intermittently

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

I have a strange issue with an AJAX view in CakePHP. This view is a sub-view within a larger view and is constructed by an AJAX call. Everything works fine for the most part but about 1 in 10 calls is going through without authentication. I put some code in my AppController to check and I am unable to figure out why this call is going without authentication intermittently. Does anyone have any idea / clues? Would be very much obliged for help or guidance...

Here is my AJAX call to load the sub-view

```
$.ajax({
            url: www_root + 'Cars/listLinksWith/Drivers/' + carId,
            type: 'ajax',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.links').html(data.content);
            }
        });
```

Here is the code in my AppController.php to debug the situation

```
if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            ...
            ... do something ...
            ...
        } else {
            if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $this->log($this->Session->read('Auth'));
            }
            CakeLog::write('error', 'AppController->beforeFilter :: request is being made without login credentials' . print_r($this->request->params, true));
        }
```

Here is the output I get in my log file when the error occurs

```
   2015-01-21 20:56:41 Error: 
    2015-01-21 20:56:41 Error: AppController->beforeFilter :: request is being made without login credentials
Array
    (
        [plugin] => 
        [controller] => Cars
        [action] => listLinksWith
        [named] => Array
            (
            )

        [pass] => Array
            (
                [0] => Drivers
                [1] => 20
            )

        [verification_url] => mksAsQ
    )
```

This is just strange and is bugging me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [`Session.checkAgent`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.7/app/Config/core.php#L193) and [`Session.autoRegenerate`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.7/app/Config/core.php#L200).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to disable `Session.autoRegenerate` in the app/Config/core.php? The fact that every 1 in 10 fails leads me to believe that it is enabled and that is why your session is getting thrown out.